# get image nested in multiple div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, google-docs

ive noticed that when you embedd a google docs iframe (onto, say your own website) it renders its pages as images. what im trying to do is get to one of those images/pages using jquery..in the html below can anyone tell me how to get the the last img? (the one with a really long source attribute value). thanks

```
<div id="content-pane" class="gview-scrollbar jfk-scrollbar" style="top: 37px; left: 0px; :    800px; height: 663px;">
     <div id="page-pane" class="">
         <div id=":0.page.0" class="page-element goog-inline-block" style="width: 739px;">
              <div>
                 <div class="highlight-pane"></div>
                 <div class="highlight-pane">
                 <div class="highlight-pane"></div>
                 <div class="highlight-pane"></div>
                 <img class="page-image" style="width: 800px; height: 1038px;display:     none;">
                 <img class="page-image" style="width: 719px;" src="?url=http%3A%2F%2Finfolab.stanford.edu%2Fpub%2Fpapers%2Fgoogle.pdf&docid=cbdffdac40189f88c8f7d1922dd915f5&a=bi&pagenumber=1&w=719">
                 <p id=":0.a11y.0" class="accessibility-text" tabindex="-1"></p>
            </div>
         </div> 
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this...already tested,

```
$("#content-pane").find("img:last").attr('src')
```

Comment: will this enable me to get at the image thats nested in the ":0.page.0" div? because the thing is they are multiple divs that represent the different pages e.g :0.page.0, :0.page.1, :0.page.2, :0.page.3 etc.